# ¿Hay una explicación "cognitiva" del 'se accidental'/'se involuntario'?

Tags: gramática, se

Hay un tipo de construcción que se llama 'se accidental'

> se me ha caído el vaso

que todos hemos aprendido.

Otras formas son

> siempre se me pierden las gafas

> se nos ha olvidado la dirección

> se me fue la idea

> se te han quemado las galletas

etc.  Pero ¿qué pasa aquí exactamente?  Es decir, tenemos un verbo con 'se' que indica que algo que no tiene agencia actúa (¿de manera pasiva?) y que los resultados de esa acción caen sobre una persona (me, te, nos, etc).  (Por cierto, ¿es este verbo en sí un 'se medio' ('se hundió el barco), una 'pasiva refleja', o...?)

Sinceramente no me interesan las etiquetas.  Más bien quiero saber cómo usar esta forma, cómo uno puede construir este tipo de frases, etc.  No se puede usar en cualquier circunstancia.  Por ejemplo, esta frase no estaría permitida

> se me aprenden los idiomas bien

aunque se parece a las otras.  ¿Es por la agencia implicada con 'aprender'?

Además, me parece que estamos ante verbos de diferentes tipos: algunos verbos se parecen más a los reflexivos ('quemarse') y otros a un tipo muy distinto ('irse'), donde el 'se' desempeña otro papel (y todo esto de la diferencia entre 'caerse' y 'caer', 'irse' y 'ir', es un tema aparte).  Además, ¿se puede usar esa construcción 'accidental' con verbos transitivos tanto como no transitivos?

Preferiría una explicación "cognitiva", plan Campillo (como hace [aquí](https://terceragramatica.com/caer-caerse/) de manera básica con caer(se)): menos un análisis sintáctico o descriptivo que algo que me ayude entenderlo de manera intuitiva.

Si tenéis alguna fuente (página web, artículo, libro) que explique esto de manera buena, os lo agradezco.

Comment: Esta página web lo explica bien https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verbs/accidental-reflexive/

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? La pregunta en si no esta muy clara, salvo cuando indicas; "*no me interesan las etiquetas. Más bien quiero saber cómo usar esta forma, cómo uno puede construir este tipo de frases, etc*".

En Español, cuando estudiamos estas expresiones de la lengua en las escuelas, no utilizamos esas "etiquetas" que suelen dar al enseñar Español para extranjeros, desde mi punto de vista algunas son muy confusas. No obstante seguiré las pautas que tu has marcado para que te sea más fácil.

La idea es explicarte lo básico para que entiendas la idea general para después tu vayas por ti solo comprobando otras expresiones del mismo tipo.

---

Hay un tipo de construcción que se llama 'se accidental'

- *se me ha caído el vaso*

que todos hemos aprendido.

Otras formas;

- *siempre se me pierden las gafas*
- *se nos ha olvidado la dirección*
- *se me fue la idea*
- *se te han quemado las galletas*

"*etc. Pero ¿qué pasa aquí exactamente? Es decir, tenemos un verbo con 'se' que indica que algo que no tiene agencia actúa (¿de manera pasiva?) y que los resultados de esa acción caen sobre una persona (me, te, nos, etc). (Por cierto, ¿es este verbo en sí un 'se medio' ('se hundió el barco), una 'pasiva refleja', o...?)*"

De esta parte apenas entiendo algo.

---

Creo que aquí se mezclan distintos tipos de conceptos y uno de ellos es confundir los diferentes usos del "**SE**", al que algunos, en este caso, dan a uno de ellos el nombre de *accidental*, con las **construcciones con verbo intransitivo pronominal y se reflejo** ;

Por tanto hay que entender de forma general sin llegar a las excepciones este tipo de oraciones, has de intentar comprender lo siguiente;

1 - Normalmente se tratan de **construcciones con verbo intransitivo pronominal y SE reflejo**.

2 - **Entender que son verbos pronominales.**
Los verbos pronominales son aquellos que se construyen incluyendo en la
terminación de su *infinitivo* un pronombre reflexivo (me, te, se, nos,
os). Estos verbos pronominales son aquellos que existen solo con el
pronombre. Por ejemplo, atreverse. No existe el verbo atrever.

3 - **Entender que son los verbos reflexivos**.
Un verbo reflexivo es aquel que indica que el resultado de la acción
realizada por el sujeto de la oración recae en el propio sujeto; dicho de
otra manera, el sujeto y el objeto directo de la oración tienen el mismo
referente. Ejem. "Bañarse", "lavarse", "peinarse", "sentarse", "mirarse",
"quedarse", "ducharse", "vestirse"...

4 - **Entender la diferencia entre verbos Pronominales y Reflexivos**.
Como he indicado más arriba los verbos pronominales son aquellos que
existen solo con el pronombre. Ejem. Atreverse.
Los verbos reflexivos pueden modificarse eliminándoles el pronombre átono.
Aunque cambia semánticamente la oración, estos verbos pueden ser empleados
sin su pronombre átono. En cambio, los verbos pronominales no pueden ser
empleados sin su pronombre.
Ejem. los verbos "Bañarse", "lavarse", "peinarse", "sentarse", "mirarse",
"quedarse", "ducharse", "vestirse"...pueden también tener la forma
"Bañar", "lavar", "peinar", "sentar", "mirar", "quedar", "duchar",
"vestir"...

---

**Ahora vamos a la parte que más te interesa**;

Escribamos las frases que tu habías enunciado anteriormente y simplemente veamos la forma reflexiva del verbo;

- *se me ha caído el vaso* - el verbo seria "caerse"
- *siempre se me pierden las gafas* - el verbo seria "perderse"
- *se nos ha olvidado la dirección* - el verbo seria "olvidarse"
- *se me fue la idea* - el verbo seria "irse"
- *se te han quemado las galletas* - el verbo seria "quemarse"

---

Cuando tu dices; "*No se puede usar en cualquier circunstancia. Por ejemplo, esta frase no se permitiría*" y pones el ejemplo;

```
            *"se me aprenden los idiomas bien"*
```

Tienes que preguntarte si el verbo "*aprender*" puede ser ó no reflexivo.
Si no lo es, no puedes hacer la construcción que deseas y tendrás que buscar uno aproximado o que indique aquello que deseas expresar, así puedes decir;

"*se me pegan bien los idiomas*" ó "*se me dan bien los idiomas*", ya que tanto los verbos "pegar" y "dar" si tienen una forma reflexiva, "pegarse" y "darse".

---

Estepero te haya servido. Saludos!

Diego M.